# Can anyone explain string.compare(_:options:range:locale:) with example?

Tags: swift, swift3

Can anyone explain what is the use of below `String` function in real life example.

`func compare(_ aString: String, options mask: String.CompareOptions = default, range: Range<String.Index>? = default, locale: Locale? = default) -> ComparisonResult`

https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1412785-compare

Answer (score 1):

Very short version: this is not a highly used method in Swift. There are often better tools. It's mostly used in ObjC.

```
import Foundation

let alice = "alice"
let bob = "bob"
let upBob = "BOB"
let bobby = "bobby"

// all are true
bob.compare(bob) == .orderedSame
bob.compare(alice) == .orderedDescending
bob.compare(upBob, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame

// This is a little weird in Swift because of how strings work. It's easier to use in ObjC
let rangeOfBob = bobby.range(of: "bob")!
bobby.compare(bob, range: rangeOfBob) == .orderedSame

bob.compare(umlaut, options: .diacriticInsensitive) == .orderedSame
```

The key lesson is that `compare` tells you the sort order. If two strings are the same, you get `.orderedSame`. If the target orders before the parameter, then you get `.orderedAscending`. Otherwise, `.orderedDescending`.

`compare` is not very "Swifty" for simple usage (you'd often use `==` and `<` instead). But it's very powerful if you need things like diacritic insensitivity. For case insensitivity, you'd just use `lowercased(with:)` in Swift.

Comment: Yes, but it's harder to use in Swift. People are often confused by having to compare against `.orderedSame`.

Comment: It also allows you more options in how two strings are considered "equal". A contrived example is `resume != résumé` in Swift but if you call the function with `options: [.diacriticInsensitive]` then they are equal. The `locale` parameter is to order the strings according to the local alphabet. I don't know enough languages to think of an example when that would have made a difference

Comment: Agreed that `compare` is more powerful (see last paragraph). But in many cases is not the most Swifty solution.